# Select an array from an array of arrays to display in uitableview (iphone)

Tags: iphone, arrays, uitableview, init

I have an array called `addArray` which I am adding array objects to:

```
NSMutableArray *addArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[addArray addObjectsFromArray: delegate.arrayobjectOne];
[addArray addObjectsFromArray: delegate.arrayobjectTwo];
// etc...
```

Now, if I only want to `init` one of these arrays to display in my table (preferably from another view controller but that's another question), how would I do this? And how would I access a specific property of each array object, e.g. `arrayobjectOne.info`?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this Example

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToAdd= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"two", nil];

NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:objectsToAdd,nil];

self.list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.list addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can say

```
someObject = [addArray objectAtIndex: someIndex];
```